# How to convert matrix to DataFrame with scala/spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have a matrix and number of columns and rows is unknow

One example Matrix is:

```
[5,1.3]
[1,5.2]
```

I want to convert it to DataFrame,column name is random,how to achive it?
this is my expect result:

```
    +-------------+----+
    |         _1  | _2 |
    +-------------+----+
    |5            |1.3 |
    |1            |5.2 |
    --------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you convert matrix to RDD and then convert RDD to DataFrame, it is not a good way but works fine in Spark 2.0.0.

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
object mat2df {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
         val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("mat2df").setMaster("local[1]")
         val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
         val values = Array(5, 1, 1.3, 5.2)
         val mat = Matrices.dense(2, 2, values).asInstanceOf[DenseMatrix]
         def toRDD(m: Matrix): RDD[Vector] = {
             val columns = m.toArray.grouped(m.numRows)
             val rows = columns.toSeq.transpose 
             val vectors = rows.map(row => new DenseVector(row.toArray))
             sc.parallelize(vectors)
         }
         val mat_rows = toRDD(mat)// matrix to rdd
         val mat_rdd = mat_rows.map(_.toArray).map{case Array(p0, p1) => (p0, p1)}
         val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate
         val df = spark.createDataFrame(mat_rdd) // rdd to dataframe
         df.show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def matrixToDataFrame(sc:SparkContext, matrix:Matrix, m_nodeColName:String):DataFrame={
val rdd = sc.parallelize(matrix.colIter.toSeq).map(x => {
      Row.fromSeq(x.toArray.toSeq)
    })
    val sc = new SQLContext(nodeContext.getSparkCtx())
    var schema = new StructType()

    val ids = ArrayBuffer[String]()
    for (i <- 0 until matrix.rowIter.size) {
      schema = schema.add(StructField(m_nodeColName +"_"+ i.toString(), DoubleType, true))
      ids.append(m_nodeColName +"_"+ i.toString())
    }

    sc.sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
}
```